# How to do exponential division when base and exponent is different between numerator and denominator?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, division

How to do division when

a<sup>x</sup> / b<sup>y</sup>

Say, a,x,b,y are distinct values.

For example,

2<sup>19</sup> / 7<sup>23</sup>. Doing mathematical operations with bigger exponents is tedious and error-prone.

Is there any way to simplify above expression such that the final decimal result wouldn't change?

Comment: This is more a math question

Comment: MrSmith, That's why added math tags

Comment: Probably better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/, since on its face this doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

7<sup>23</sup> = 2<sup>23 log<sub>2</sub>7</sup>.

2<sup>19</sup>/2<sup>23 log<sub>2</sub>7</sup> = 2<sup>19 - 23 log<sub>2</sub>7</sup>

Comment: Even after simplifying getting huge exponents to calculate...Is there any better way @Severin Pappadeux

Comment: @Manikandankk Well, if you use base 10, then using the same trick 2^(19 - 23 log2(7))=10^(log10(2)*(19-23*log2(7)))=10^(-13.717685)=10^0.282315*10^-14=1.915645*10^-14